# I'm getting 'org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component' error while configuringa dynamic web project with tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

This is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-
    app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

     <display-name>VideoPlayer</display-name>

     <welcome-file-list>

        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>

        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>

        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>

        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>

        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>

      </welcome-file-list>

      <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.videoplayer.controller.UploadServlet</servlet-class>

     </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

This is my Servlet :

```
      package com.videoplayer.controller;


    import java.io.File;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import java.util.Iterator;

    import java.util.List;



    import javax.servlet.ServletException;

    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;

    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;

    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;

    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;



    /**

     * Servlet implementation class UploadServlet

     */

    @WebServlet("/UploadServlet")

    public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



        /**

         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()

         */

        public UploadServlet() {

            super();

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        }



        /**

         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

         */

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



        /**

         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

         */

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            boolean isMultiPart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);



            if(isMultiPart)

            {

                DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);



                try {

                    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);



                    Iterator<FileItem> it = items.iterator();



                    while(it.hasNext())

                    {

                        FileItem item = it.next();



                        if(!(item.isFormField()))

                        {

                            String fieldname = item.getFieldName();

                            String filename = item.getName();

                            long fileSize = item.getSize();



                            System.out.println("Field Name is :"+fieldname);

                            System.out.println("File Name is :"+filename);

                            System.out.println("File Size is :"+fileSize);



                            String filepath = "C:"+File.separator;



                            File video = new File(filepath);



                            item.write(video);

                        }

                    }

                } catch (FileUploadException e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        }



    }
```

I observed that whenever I create any servlet mapping,tomcat7 is throwing this exception.I didn't understand what went wrong with web.xml.I tried it removing @WebServlet in servlet, but still the result was same...Could anyone please help me with this isuue??Thanks in advance :)

Below is the full StackTrace :

```
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start

    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/VideoPlayer]]

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/VideoPlayer]]

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)

        ... 7 more

    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)

        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:263)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:142)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

        ... 7 more

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException

        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)

        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)

        ... 21 more

    Sep 12, 2014 9:47:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal

    SEVERE: A child container failed during start

    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

        ... 7 more

    Sep 12, 2014 9:47:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.

    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

        ... 7 more

    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

        ... 9 more

    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)

        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

        ... 11 more

    Sep 12, 2014 9:47:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause

    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9080"]

    Sep 12, 2014 9:47:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause

    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

    Sep 12, 2014 9:47:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal

    INFO: Stopping service Catalina

    Sep 12, 2014 9:47:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy

    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9080"]

    Sep 12, 2014 9:47:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy

    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include the relevant search tag for the programming language used (looks like Java?). If you don't do this, your question will not get any attention from the right people, and you might not get any answers.

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace in your question?

Comment: Hi David,Thanks for responding.I have added the full stack trace.Please provide me some solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the root cause of the problem is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
```

It means that either the commons-fileupload jar is not found on the classpath, or you have two conflicting versions of that jar. Make sure that the jar is included under the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your webapp. Also make sure that you have only one version of that jar on the classpath and that the version of the jar deployed in Tomcat is the same one used to compile the application.